# React Native using multiple different navigators within the *same page*

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a mobile app, where the app provides several features. There are 2 main group of features: user-specific features (like wish-list, etc) and general features (like news, about us, etc). I am new to React Native, and I want to have these 2 groups in different navigation "sections": the user-specific stuff should be inside a `BottomTabNavigator`, while the general stuff should be inside a `DrawerNavigator`.

My problem is very similar to [How to use Multiple Navigators in React Native version 6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69240150/how-to-use-multiple-navigators-in-react-native-version-6-x?fbclid=IwAR0bc_3TPfY9FenSxNBTqHV80P71J7wHkPIpJwGhLxBLOau9kJvQ3VXn_8g), but unlike in that problem, I want to have **different** elements in my tabs.

I have tried nesting the two navigators into one, like this:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { PaperProvider, MD3LightTheme as DefaultTheme } from 'react-native-paper';
import {SafeAreaView, View, Text} from "react-native";
import {StatusBar} from 'expo-status-bar';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Header from "./components/Header";
/* *screen imports here* */


const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function TabNav() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="Wishes" component={ScreenWishlist} />
            <Tab.Screen name="History" component={ScreenHistory} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}

export default function App()
{
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:"#800"}}>
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
                <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:"#fff"}}>
                    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
                        <StatusBar translucent={false} hidden={false} style={"light"} backgroundColor={'#800'} />

                        <NavigationContainer>
                            <Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{
                                header: Header
                            }}>
                                <Drawer.Screen name="tabs" component={TabNav} />
                                <Drawer.Screen name="News" component={ScreenNews} />
                                <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={ScreenAboutUs} />
                            </Drawer.Navigator>
                        </NavigationContainer>

                    </PaperProvider>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Here the problem was that I've lost the bottom navigator after changing some screens.

I have also tried using two `NavigationContainer`s, like this:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'; // make sure it's at the top and there's nothing else before it
import { PaperProvider, MD3LightTheme as DefaultTheme } from 'react-native-paper';
import {SafeAreaView, View, Text} from "react-native";
import {StatusBar} from 'expo-status-bar';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Header from "./components/Header";
/* *screen imports here* */

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App()
{
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:"#800"}}>
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
                <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:"#fff"}}>
                    <PaperProvider>

                        <NavigationContainer>
                            <Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{
                                header: Header
                            }}>
                                <Drawer.Screen name="News" component={ScreenNews} />
                                <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={ScreenAboutUs} />
                            </Drawer.Navigator>
                            
                        </NavigationContainer>

                        <NavigationContainer>
                            <Tab.Navigator>
                                <Tab.Screen name="Wishes" component={ScreenWishlist} />
                                <Tab.Screen name="History" component={ScreenHistory} />
                            </Tab.Navigator>
                        </NavigationContainer>

                    </PaperProvider>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Here the problem was that it rendered like it had 2 different screens, entire screen split in the middle, and the two screens worked independently. I want only 1 screen rendered at once, and that should cover the whole screen - except the navigation buttons of course, I want both navigation controller buttons rendered all the time.

[image: The "dual screen" which I want to avoid]
[image: The opened navi which I want to keep, just like the bottom navi]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.

You can use the [Stack Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator), that doesn't render any buttons, so you can make your own buttons with React Native Paper [Drawer](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/Drawer/DrawerSection) and [BottomNavigation](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/BottomNavigation/).

You probably want to highlight the selected navi menu, so the user knows which screen are they on. To do that, you need to get the current screen's name and check it for each button. You can get the current screen like this (from ChatGPT):

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
const currentScreen = navigation.dangerouslyGetState().routes[navigation.dangerouslyGetState().index].name;
```

Or you can set a global state (Redux or Context) in the `useEffect()` of each screen.